# Converting Qt's QML code to C++

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

Is there any way to convert **Qt**'s **QML** code to **C++**? For me it is easier to read C++ since I have not got any experience in **QML** yet.

Comment: You can check QtQuick parser source to have an idea how to do that. But I don't think it's an easy task. Moreover, I do not see much sense in this. QML and C++ are too different. QML is declarative language C++ is imperative OO one.

Comment: So if you can why don't work with qwidget applications instead of qml?

Comment: @Moia: I have some source code in QML and I want to change some stuff.

Comment: That's time to learn QML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to use Qt Quick without writing any QML. (Even though people like me have been asking for the ability to do it since Qt Quick was first released...) There is no C++ interface to instantiate Qt Quick components except to pass a QML document into one of the `QQml` classes.

That said, it is POSSIBLE to do it entirely in a C++ file, but it's really quite messy and it involves writing small QML documents inside strings. If you really want to try, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890372/add-objects-to-qml-layout-from-c) goes into detail on how to do it, but I think you'll find that it isn't going to make things any easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Qt Widget instead of Qt QML and write C++ as you like.